# Concerns around gracefully handling multiple offers & visa (Germany)

Tags: visas, germany, working-visas

I have an offer from company Z (in Berlin) & also have a visa appointment coming up on 12th July. I'm also in the final stages of the interviews with another company N (in Berlin) but the confirmation of the offer won't be known until the end of next week

So my doubt is

1. Should I just postpone the visa appointment by a week or two?
2. Should I just go for the visa appointment on 12th July for company Z and depending on the result of company N I can update my visa later?

AFAIK company Z does not have any penalty clause on their contract. I've signed the contract but it kept getting invalidated due to delay in travel, visa appointments

This is the German National Employment Visa we're talking about (not EU blue card).